# WildcardType to ParameterizedType

Tags: java, generics, reflection, guava

I have the bean property of type `List<? extends Number>` and the list of candidate implementation classes with their constructors. I recursively seek candidates for constructor parameters.

One of the candidate constructors is `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E>)`

I'm trying to resolve the type parameters and constructor parameters using Guava, but when there's a chain of wildcard types, I get something like: `? extends capture#3-of ? extends capture#2-of ? extends capture#1-of ? extends ...`

```
public static <T extends Object> void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TypeToken<?> propTt = new TypeToken<List<? extends Number>>() {
    };

    TypeToken<?> candidate = propTt.getSubtype(ArrayList.class);

    TypeToken<?> constructorResult;

    Constructor<?> cons = ArrayList.class.getConstructor(Collection.class);

    // java.util.ArrayList<? extends java.lang.Number>
    constructorResult = candidate.constructor(cons).getReturnType();
    System.out.println(constructorResult);


    // java.util.Collection<? extends E>
    Type param = cons.getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
    System.out.println(param);

    // java.util.Collection<? extends capture#1-of ? extends class java.lang.Number>
    TypeToken<?> resolvedParam = constructorResult.resolveType(param);
    System.out.println(resolvedParam);
}
```

This happens although we can't use wildcards as type parameters for `new`. The following is illegal:

```
List<?> x = new ArrayList<?>();
List<? extends Number> y = new ArrayList<? extends Number>();
```

Instead we write:

```
List<?> x = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<? extends Number> y = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

or automate the latter by using the diamond operator.

The desired type of `resolvedParam` is `java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.Number>`.

`com.google.common.reflect.Types` has the `newParameterizedType()` method where I could pass the former wildcards manually resolved to parameterized types or classes, but this method is package-private. I'm uncertain my workaround:

```
package com.google.common.reflect;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable;
import java.lang.reflect.WildcardType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestWildcard {
    public static <T extends Object> void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TypeToken<?> propTt = new TypeToken<List<? extends Number>>() {
        };

        TypeToken<?> candidate = propTt.getSubtype(ArrayList.class);

        TypeToken<?> constructorResult;

        Constructor<?> cons = ArrayList.class.getConstructor(Collection.class);

        // new java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Number>();
        constructorResult = resolveConstructorResult(candidate);
        System.out.println(constructorResult);

        // java.util.Collection<? extends E>
        Type param = cons.getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
        System.out.println(param);

        // java.util.Collection<? extends capture#1-of ? extends class java.lang.Number>
        TypeToken<?> resolvedParam = constructorResult.resolveType(param);
        System.out.println(resolvedParam);
    }

    static TypeToken<?> resolveConstructorResult(TypeToken<?> candidate) {
        Type ct = candidate.getType();
        if (ct instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) ct;
            Class<?> ptClazz = ((Class<?>) pt.getRawType());
            TypeVariable<?>[] tvars = ptClazz.getTypeParameters();
            Type[] targs = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
            boolean doIt = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < targs.length; i++) {
                if (targs[i] instanceof WildcardType) {
                    WildcardType wt = (WildcardType) targs[i];
                    TypeToken<?> ubound1 = TypeToken.of(wt.getUpperBounds()[0]);
                    TypeToken<?> ubound2 = TypeToken.of(tvars[i].getBounds()[0]);
                    if (ubound1.isSubtypeOf(ubound2)) {
                        doIt = true;
                        targs[i] = ubound1.getType();
                    } else if (ubound2.isSubtypeOf(ubound1)) {
                        doIt = true;
                        targs[i] = ubound2.getType();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (doIt) {
                pt = GuavaReflectAccessHelper.newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(pt.getOwnerType(), ptClazz, targs);
                candidate = TypeToken.of(pt);
            }
        }
        return candidate;
    }

    private static class GuavaReflectAccessHelper {

        public static ParameterizedType newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(@Nullable Type ownerType, Class<?> rawType,
                Type... arguments) {
            return Types.newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(ownerType, rawType, arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom `newParameterizedType` can be implemented with `TypeResolver.where()` (not to be confused with `TypeToken.where()`). The related part in my `resolveConstructorResult()` in the question can be changed like this:

```
        if (doIt) {
            pt = (ParameterizedType)newParameterizedType(ptClazz, targs);
            candidate = TypeToken.of(pt);
        }
    }
    return candidate;
}

public static Type newParameterizedType(Class<?> cls, Type... args) {
    TypeResolver resolver = new TypeResolver();
    TypeVariable<?>[] tvars = cls.getTypeParameters();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        resolver = resolver.where(tvars[i], args[i]);
    }
    return resolver.resolveType(dumbToGenericType(cls).getType());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> TypeToken<? extends T> dumbToGenericType(Class<T> cls) {
    return (TypeToken<T>)TypeToken.of(Object.class).getSubtype(cls);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting wildcard type to ParameterizedType does not sound good here, but you can just implement that interface on your own.

Or use some other library that does support more dynamic creation: 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/TypeUtils.html
And probably many other libraries.

In guava you can only do something like that:

```
static <K, V> TypeToken<Map<K, V>> mapToken(TypeToken<K> keyToken, TypeToken<V> valueToken) {
  return new TypeToken<Map<K, V>>() {}
    .where(new TypeParameter<K>() {}, keyToken)
    .where(new TypeParameter<V>() {}, valueToken);
}
...
TypeToken<Map<String, BigInteger>> mapToken = mapToken(
   TypeToken.of(String.class),
   TypeToken.of(BigInteger.class));
TypeToken<Map<Integer, Queue<String>>> complexToken = mapToken(
   TypeToken.of(Integer.class),
   new TypeToken<Queue<String>>() {});
```

It might be enough for you.

Comment: All good, but `List<? extends SomeClass & SomeInterface>` can't exist. Wildcards always have one upper bound.

Comment: You are right here, but if you are normalizing your generics to ParameterizedType type you might get type like this: `<T extends SomeClass & SomeInterface> List<T>` (as method return type, or T from class and as field)
But yep, I forgot that they only added support for upper/lower bounds reflection API but not in language itself, but you still should think about case I mentioned above.

Comment: How to rewrite `mapToken()` to accept an arbitrary raw class and an array of actual type arguments? There's no `TypeParameter.of(Type)` and `TypeToken.of(Class)` returns the raw type token, not a parameterized type needed for `where()`

Comment: `TypeToken.of(Object.class).getSubtype(Map.class)` ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with this library, at least I don't see any way, you can use some other one